# Different frequencies of digital signals over long distance

Tags: digital-logic, rs422

I am working on a solution which will need to transport some different frequencies of digital signals over 10-20 meters.

I have worked out a design with the following components:

[image]

PCB with

- An ESP32
- An sx1509 I2C multiplexer
  (https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/sx1509.pdf) to
  shift the logic level from 3.3 to 5V (and to get enough digital i/O
  pins)
- One ISL32272E RS422 driver (https://www.renesas.com/us/en/www/doc/datasheet/isl32172e-272e-174e-179e.pdf)
- One ISL32173E RS422 receiver
  (https://www.renesas.com/us/en/www/doc/datasheet/isl32173e-273e-175e-275e-177e-277e.pdf)

And ~10m away I have the following

- PCB with connectors
- One ISL32173E RS422 receiver
  (https://www.renesas.com/us/en/www/doc/datasheet/isl32173e-273e-175e-275e-177e-277e.pdf)
- One ISL32272E RS422 driver
  (https://www.renesas.com/us/en/www/doc/datasheet/isl32172e-272e-174e-179e.pdf)
- 8x active IR sensors; output is 5V logic signal
- 3x ultrasonic sensors (JSN-SR04T); sending 40 KHz signal after being triggered
- 1x addressable led strip; requiring 800KHz signal

I want to use 3 UTP awg22 cables to transort the signals

Feedback, hints or tips to improve the design wrt flaws, cost and reliability are appreciated.

And I have 2 specific question:

1. Would I still need an additional component after the SX1509 (component
   A) to eliminate picking up EMI or any ground loop / potential
   mismatch?
2. Could I use VCC=3.3V at the RS422 driver side and VCC=5V at the
   receiver side (I do not have any other need for 5V so it would save
   me a 5V pwr supply component at driver side). Consequence is that
   the driver will output a Differential VOUT of 2.6V but I am not sure
   if this will suffice at receiver side at a guaranteed min speed of
   800KHz as it has a Input High Voltage of 2.2V at Vcc=5V.

thx!

Comment: either tie the GROUNDS together across that 10 meters, so your Common Mode voltages do not exceed the differential-signals tolerances; or use Fiber Optics.

Comment: 5V logic over 20 meters is highly questionable. It's gonna be an EMC nightmare. How do you power the IR sensors etc?

Comment: Don't try to use I2C for this.  Use an MCU on both ends with the RS422 and serial UARTs and if necessary implement an error detection and retry protocol.  Send readings over the link, don't put the link in the middle of the task of taking readings.  Also build an adapter so you can substitute a PC for either end in testing, either injecting simulated data or analyzing real data.

Comment: thx, ground and pwr goes via a 2x9awg cable. Will be battery voltage (6.6V) and there will be a  DC-DC converter on the pcb on the left side of the drawing

Comment: @Chris, I2C is local on the pcb to control the multiplexer which will output 5V, I need that as the ESP does not have that many pins. I did think of using 2 MCU's but this will increase the programming complexity so if I could resolve it in Hardware that would be nice... I am also looking for fast response times between sensors and light and adding a "slow" serial connection and a second MCU would degrade this to some extend.

Comment: That's a mistaken analysis.  Keeping all of the details of sensor reading or actuation contained to one side or the other and passing only "conclusions" or "decisions" back and forth will in fact be fastest.  You can run serial UARTs quite fast, if the electrical connection can maintain sufficient fidelity.  And by having your own software on both ends, you can tune for the maximum performance with or without error handling.  This will easily run well above the speed of perception.

Comment: @Chris, thx. I will give it some more thought. There are more components I did not draw in as I meant to focus the question on the "long distance signal". There is also an audio output, SD-card, a pusbutton, LTE and Bluetooth which were meant to come on the "left side of the drawing" (due to physical placement of antenna's and speaker). I do like the segregation but I cannot put it all left or all right...